# Ambiguous Firebase Analytics Console Error

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Anyone know what this error is about? It shows up each time I open an event in Firebase Analytics Console.

[image]

The only thing I can think of that has changed recently is that my user's role has changed from `Viewer` to `Editor`.

Having recently switched from `Fabric` to `Firebase` for analytics and crash reporting (Android), you can see why it does not inspire a lot of confidence when this pops up all the time.

Thanks in advance!

--- EDIT ---

I have found some issues from within the console:

[image]

Comment: Such an expansion of privileges should definitely not result in an error. Can you check if any relevant error messages show up in the JavaScript console? If that doesn't seem to help, it might be a good moment to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen for the very quick response. I added the console log to my question.

Comment: Hmmm... that seems odd. Please give it a shot in a different browser, or in an incognito window with all extensions disabled. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried in incognito and another browser, and still the same. Going to reach out to Firebase support. Thanks for your help @FrankvanPuffelen!